# Why is it not possible to change the default schema to user schema for the Windows Login

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

[image: the properties of the windows login]

In this picture, you can see if I login using windows authentication, the default user and schema are dbo.

I have a database called trunk2 and its default user is trunk2 and default schema is trunk2.

If I login as "trunk2", I can access the schema a"trunk2" as the default schema

But if I login using the windows authentication, I am not able to populate the schema "trunk2"  as the default schema for the database trunk2

It is populating the schema "dbo" as the default schema. Why ?

How can I login using the Windows login and access the schema "trunk2" as the default schema of the database "trunk2"?

Please see in the below picture, for the login "trunk2", I have no problem in accessing the default schema "trunk2" for database "trunk2"  and default user "trunk2"

[image: if I login as trunk2, I can see my default user and schema as trunk2]

Answer (score 1):

you cannot assign a default schema in SQL Server to a Windows-authenticated set of users.

Why? it is by design.

Look at the following link:

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918346

Comment: It's not an issue with Windows authentication, per se, it's when Windows Authentication is being used to grant access via *group membership*. If you add the individual Windows users as logins to SQL Server they can have default schemas applied.

Comment: Yes, SQL users can have default schemas, but if we want to access these users using Windows login, we cannot access their defined default schemas, but only the schema "dbo"

Comment: I want to access the database "trunk2", but only through the windows login, then it is giving me problem by accessing "dbo", but not the assigned the schema. is there any workaround?

Comment: No, I meant that if you add the windows login for the *user* `YOURDOMAIN\User123456` then you should be able to assign a default schema for that user. If you add the windows login `YOURDOMAIN\SomeGroupThatUser123456IsAMemberOf` then you can't apply a default schema for the user via that group membership.

Answer (score 1):

this is sort of Microsoft BS... given the fact that we have restored a database with a set of tables associated to "dbo" and creating some stored procedures in our client applicatoin (after using a "trusted connection") puts them into domain\username schema, not into dbo although it'S group entry in SQL management studio has clearly being associated "dbo" as default schema.

Thereby executing the stored precedures after their creation gets me an ugly error "the stored procedure is in different schema than the table" and an empty resultset. However the error level reported by the SQL server is not high enough to create an exception that could be catched in an try/error code sequence....  and when it's not an error then data is missing in the client app. Very ugly, very ugly.

A workaround was to fix the schema membership of the freshly created stored procedures  with "alter schema dbo transfer [domain\username].[sp name]" but with houndreds of windows users that gets me an administrative nightmare.... and this is still in SQL Server 2014

Comment: I this still a problem in 2022?